# Fluid simulation not baking, no fluid input object in the scene

Tags: mesh, fluid-simulation

I keep getting the **no fluid input objects in the scene** error every time I try to bake please help, I'm just trying to bake a simple text [image]

I'm using blender 2.78c on windows 8.1

Comment: What do you mean "*bake a simple text *"?

Comment: ^ I meant it's just a text, not like some pro animation or something, 4 letters that's all. All I wanted to do was a melting animation. ;-; The struggle is real.

Comment: It appears your text object is set as the domain. This is probably not what you wanted? Normally you'd have a separate cube as the domain and your melting object set as "fluid" (ie, supplying fluid to the domain). Did you set some other object as a fluid source? The error says it can't find one.

Answer (score 1):

As @JtheNinja said above, you didn't set the simulation right.

The "text object" (it must be converted to mesh for this to work) must be set as "fluid", and another surrounding shape (usually a big cube) must be set as "domain", and then baked. As soon as you start baking, the big cube domain will become a fluid-like shape resembling your text:

[image]

Without any other setting, or obstacle, this will generate a fluid "text shaped" object that will suddenly splash onto the "ground" (ie: the domain bottom face):

[image]

With higher domain resolutions, the fluid-like shape will better fit the text shape, of course (here I used 120 with other standard default fluid settings)